# Run Query in external php file through zencart Order.php

Tags: php, zen-cart

I am running a PHP based application and on the other hand, I have Zencart based website where I want to run one the php file of first application through order.php file of zencart.

order.php function:

```
function send_order_email($zf_insert_id, $zf_mode)
```

Inside this, I want to run the query of another application that have the code:

```
//external.php
$affid = isset($_SESSION['affid']) ? $_SESSION['affid'] : ''; 

if (!$affid){
    exit;
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET type='2' where OrderID = '{$affid}'",DBH);
}
```

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Not yet but think include() and ajax call won't solve my problem

Comment: Why not just put the external.php code inside of the send_order_email function?...

Comment: @Clay Both dbs are different

Comment: You could create a new connection to the external database just to do the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has called the external php file to run:

```
 echo "<img src=\"http://domain.com/external.php\" />";
```